# How do i restart IIS Express in VS 2017 community

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I have ASP.NET Web API. When i run the application using VS the IIS express used to be available in system tray from where i could shutdown.

In Visual Studio 2017 i do not see IIS express is available in system tray.

How do restart  IIS express in VS 2017

Comment: It should be in your system tray. You can always kill it with `taskkill /IM iisexpress.exe /F`